# CSS centering query

Tags: css, embed, center

I do not have access to anything other than an "HTML box" - that's it. So although there might be many better ways of doing this, my options are a little limited. I cannot add ANY code, other to a simple "box". As such almost every solution I have seen so far with Google does not work. I am permitted to embed a link to a page - but I have ZERO control of the rest of the page / stylesheet etc.

At the moment it works, but everything is ***left justified*** which looks grim, I would like to centre it but ideally NOT use the obsolete  command. Is there a way to do it without having access to the rest of the page code?

I need to convert the following to display as centered text:-

< embed type="text/html" src="targetwebsite.com/" width="300" height="600">

I can make it work well with < center> < embed type="text/html" src="targetwebsite.com" width="300" height="600"> but I am trying to replace the < center> tag with something that is not obsolete.

I am aware of iframe, however due to issues with the host site, this causes other problems. So please do not tell me I need to use iframe and to edit things outside of the little HTML box - I do not have that option sadly. Thank you.

(extra space after the first < is to make it display!)

Answer (score 0):

iframe and embed are is so hard cases for css.

But you can solve centering or width problems with a container div like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 

<style>
    .framecontainer {
        border:1px solid red;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    iframe {
        /* if you wanna iframe 100%;
        width:100% !important;

        */
    }
</style>
    <div class="framecontainer">

        <embed type="text/html" src="http://cebraililhan.com/"  width="500" height="200">



</div>


<div class="framecontainer">

  

<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>

</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but sadly as I explained, iframe does NOT work properly on their site, so I cannot use that. I have to do everything from the small "HTML box" and iframe causes issues with their site - so cannot use it.

Hence trying to see if there is any option other than using <center> that will work and does NOT need iframe or other code outside of the little HTmL box.

Thanks again for your thoughts though.

Comment: @GuyTeigh hi, can you share link or files on codepen?